# Dynamically Add DropDownList to radGrid ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am trying to add Dropdownlist to each row of a radGrid in the ItemTemplate dynamically. So basically when the radGrid loads I want to add DropDOwnList to each row and add certain data to it based on the id created. How would I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with below code.

```
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="ADDCombo">
            <ItemTemplate>

            </ItemTemplate>
           </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

...............

```
 if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;

        //get data key
        string strID = item.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString();


        RadComboBox RadComboBox2 = new RadComboBox();
        // bind your combo here
        item["ADDCombo"].Controls.Add(RadComboBox2);
    }
```